# Drive Letter assigned to system reserved partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I recently removed my ubuntu installation because I didn't want to go through GRUB every time I turned on my PC. That worked fine. Now in file explorer I have a 100MB partition. I know that this partition is the system reserved one because in drive management it shows the system reserved partition under drive letter e:

How can I hide the drive? I don't want to mess up my windows installation. I tried removing the drive letter but windows says I can't change drive letter on the current boot or pagefile drive.

OS : Windows 8.1 Update 1

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't want to go through GRUB?"

Comment: @Steven I didn't want to have to select the Windows option in the GRUB bootlader. I know that I could change the default option but this is the only computer I have so I didn't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue myself. I had a program called MiniTool Partition Wizard which is what I used to remove Ubuntu and rebuild the MBR. I used that and removed the drive letter from the system reserved partition and it worked like a charm.

--------------------------------------------------HOW I DID IT --------------------------------------------------------------
Using MiniTool Partition Wizard 9,

- Click On Partition
- On the left side options list, there is an option called change drive letter.
  Click on that and set the drive letter to none.

Problem Solved

-Thor

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the `Disk management` tool, by clicking on `Change Drive Letter and Paths` and then `Remove`.

See also [Change, add, or remove a drive letter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: "I tried removing the drive letter but windows says I can't change drive letter on the current boot or pagefile drive."